# Laravel Updating both data and files in one form using Ajax? when method/type='PUT'

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, laravel, request

Well, when I do not use ajax to send data to server directly from form by adding  hidden _method parameter where value is 'PUT'-> everything just work like a charm for updating a form. But when I tried same things with ajax receiving null for $request object in controller update function. Right now I am feeling frightened that for delete I have to use method='POST'.

I used both method='POST' or type='POST' but no luck.

```
Route::resource('contents', 'ContentController');
let url_content_update = "{{ route('contents.update', ':id') }}";

WebApp.ContentController.onClickUpdateButton = function () {
    var _id = $("#form_id").data('_id');
    var form = $("#form_id")[0];
    var formData = new FormData(form);
    console.log(formData.get('title'));// console print "I am title" just fine.
    $.ajax({
         headers: {
            'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
        },
        url: url_content_update.replace(':id', _id),
        method: 'PUT',
        contentType:false ,
        processData: false,
        data: formData,
        xhr: function() {
            var xhr = new window.XMLHttpRequest();
            xhr.upload.addEventListener("progress", function(evt) {
                if (evt.lengthComputable) {
                    var percentComplete = evt.loaded / evt.total;
                    $('#status').html('Upload a file (compulsory):<b> Uploading -> ' + (Math.round(percentComplete * 100)) + '% </b>');
                }
            }, false);

            return xhr;
        },
        success: function (result) {

        },
        error: function (jqXHR, exception) {
        }

    })

}
```

**Controller:**
**received value of $id=383 successfully.**
**But null found in $request object;**

```
 public function update(Request $request,  $id)
    {
        $content = Content::find($id); 
        $content->app_id=$request->app_cat; 
        $content->cat_id=$request->category;
        $content->sub_cat_id=$request->subcategory;
        $content->title=$request->title;
        $content->content_type=$request->type;
        if($request->type==3||$request->type==4||$request->type==5){
            //return json_encode($request->hasFile('any_file'));
            if($request->hasFile('any_file')){
                $content->content=$this->storeFile($request);
            }
        }else{
            $content->content=$request->content;
        }

        $fileNameToStore='no_image.jpg';
        if($request->hasFile('cover_image')){
            $this->validate($request,[
                'cover_image'=>'image|nullable|max:1999'
            ]);
            $content->cover_image=$this->storeImage($request);
        }

        $content->save();
        $output = array("message"=>"Content updated successfully", "status" => "200");
        echo json_encode($output);
    }
```

Comment: how is your route looks like?

Comment: PUT|PATCH | contents/{content}                                       | contents.update       | App\Http\Controllers\ContentController@update

Comment: see my answer, let me know if it helps.

Comment: @AndySong Thank you.. It's worked like a magic. Just adding ***formData.append('_method', 'PUT');*** solved the problem "Fantastic"

Comment: can you upvote and accept my answer please lol

Answer (score 1):

This is a known [issue](https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/13457) since 2016, here is how you submit a `put` in traditional form.

```html
<form action="/foo/bar" method="POST">
    @method('PUT')
    @csrf
</form>
```

so basically if you want to use `FormData` you cannot use `put` or `patch` as the method, you have to use `post`. Also, you need to tell laravel the request was supposed to be `PUT` so your code has to be like this

```js
   ...
            var formData = new FormData(form);
            //this line is equivalent with @method('PUT') in traditional form
            formData.append('_method', 'PUT');
   ...
            //this line is equivalent with method="POST" in traditional form
            method: 'POST',
```

Unfortunately, this is the only solution if you want to use `FormData`.